# TortoiseSVN show log very slow on working copy stored on network share

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, nfs

I'm using a working copy stored on a samba network share.  It seems to work fine; except...

Under windows I can do "svn log -l 100 -v ." on the working copy and get results in <1 second.  However if I use TortiseSVN to right click and show log it hangs for several minutes while using >30Mbps of network bandwidth.

Are there known issues or configs needed for Tortise to handle a network stored working copy?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this thread is a little old, but... I found it, so someone else will likely find it too. This is not necessarily a solution it's what I know, and what I've experienced in the past and more recently.

I looked into this issue quite a while ago. We suffer from the same issue. Sluggish response times on Windows workstations +  Linux web servers with SMB shares that house each user's checkout.

The amount of time it takes to commit/update/query is dreadful. We've all just learned to live with it because of how our development environments are defined--They are all semi-remote rather than on our local machines, which is sad for developers, but it's how the security officer & sysadmin decided to do things way back when.

To be fair, and not blame it all on TortoiseSVN, we've had issues with sluggish response times in other applications too. I personally experience horrible delays when editing any code in my checkouts using Eclipse.

TortoiseSVN has apparently added some info to their FAQ since I last looked (forever ago):

**Can I create a local repository on a network directory?**
http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#repoonshare

**Can I keep my repository on a network share instead of setting up a server?**
http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#reponoserver

Comment: The links address putting the repo on a share (rather than a working copy).  I have a server running the repo (great) but I want to share working copies as well.

Comment: If you're able, try updating to TortoiseSVN 1.7... see if you notice any improvements. Looks like it was just released yesterday, and is claiming performance enhancements.

!!!BEFORE YOU INSTALL THE NEW COPY!!!
http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html#wc-upgrade

Full Change Log: http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the following link describes how svn 1.7 in general made this "subversion working copy on network drive (nfs/samba)" even worse than it was in svn 1.6:

http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2012-02/0413.shtml

It would be great if there was a option in svn 1.7 to turn on this SQLite exclusive locking mode.

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't put working copies onto network drives!

Comment: This is not a helpful solution.

Comment: Why not?  Because the tool can't handle it?  Thats a problem with the tool; not the process.  Why wouldn't developers want to actually see what eachother are doing?  I do this regularly in my current CM system.